# step through test code with maven and intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Is it possible to step through your test code with Maven and IntelliJ? I know you can attach the debugger to running process but i can't figure out how to attach it when i run `mvn clean test` in IntelliJ.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just run the test in debug mode in Intellij?

Comment: how do i do that? i set a breakpoint and clicked the bug icon to run my tests, but it never broke.

Comment: If the test did in fact run, then that just means your breakpoint wasn't being hit.

Comment: Try putting your cursor within the test method you want to bug, then right click and select "Debug 'yourTestMethod()'". If the test runs, you should get a Debug window at the bottom of the main intellij window.

Comment: i have breakpoints in my test cases and in production that i know are being tested. Can't get anything to break. boo

Comment: @David Make sure you have the \@Test annotation at the top of your method.  Otherwise Intellij will just think it's some unused non-test code and find another test in the test class to run.

Comment: i thought the @Test annotation was used by JUnit? Removing the annotation made JUnit skip it.

Comment: does it matter that i have the following at the top of the class `RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)`?

Comment: @David Right, \@Test is used by JUnit. DON'T remove it.  Don't know anything about RobolectricTestRunner...